# How to select multiple idexed ids using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, template-literals

i have 6 `div`s with `id` `wrapperX` (`X` is number 1 till 6)
when I want to change its background color with `for` loop
 error show on the log which says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`
when I'm not use template literal it works but I must write the code one by one

```
// show error
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
  let eleSelect = document.getElementById(`wrapper${i}`);
  eleSelect.style.setProperty('background-color', 'green');
  console.log(eleSelect);
}
// it works 
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
  let eleSelect = document.getElementById('wrapper0');
  // i must repeat the code till 5
  eleSelect.style.setProperty('background-color', 'green');
  console.log(eleSelect);
}
```

css code (i think it's necessary to include here) :

```
#wrapper0, #wrapper1, #wrapper2, #wrapper3, #wrapper4, #wrapper5{
  width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: black;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="wrapper0"></div><div id="wrapper1"></div><div id="wrapper2"></div><div id="wrapper3"></div><div id="wrapper4"></div><div id="wrapper5"></div>
```

Comment: Are there elements with the following ids: wrapper0, wrapper2, wrapper3, ..., wrapper5 ?

Comment: Could you add the HTML you are trying to modify?

Comment: what is `tempEleSelect` ... how is it related to the **unused** variable `eleSelect`

Comment: @NiceBooks yes,  wait I'll add the code as well

Comment: but where's wrapper0, wrapper2, wrapper3 wrapper4 and wrapper5?

Comment: @Bravo i was forgot to edit

Comment: You said *"X is number 1 till 6"*, but `i` starts at 0...

Comment: and ends at 5, not 6 - you probably need `for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {`

Comment: Your second example in the question "// it works", works because you are doing the same settings on the same element ('wrapper1") 5 times (loops: 0,1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: i think I'm making dumn question here, sorry for that i'm new in javascript. anyway thanks for y'all comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not have a wrapper0 element but your loop counter is set to 0

solution:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) { 
  let eleSelect = document.getElementById(`wrapper${i}`);
  tempEleSelect.style.setProperty('background-color', 'green');
  console.log(tempEleSelect);
}
```

Comment: i was about to make my answer based on @Megaptera novaeangliae's comment, anyway thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

###### Method-1

In the first solution, all `<div>` elements are selected and the `background-color` style of all elements whose id attribute starts with `wrapper` is set to `green`.

```js
/** 
 * In the solution below, all <div> elements are selected and the background-color
 * style of all elements whose id attribute starts with "wrapper" is set to green.
 */
let containers = document.querySelectorAll('div');

containers.forEach(element => {
  if(element.getAttribute("id").substring(0, 7) === "wrapper") {
    element.style.setProperty('background-color', 'green');
    console.log(element);
  }
});
```

```css
#wrapper0, #wrapper1, #wrapper2, #wrapper3, #wrapper4, #wrapper5{
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper0"></div>
<div id="wrapper1"></div>
<div id="wrapper2"></div>
<div id="wrapper3"></div>
<div id="wrapper4"></div>
<div id="wrapper5"></div>
```

###### Method-2

In the second solution, all items whose `id` value is in the range `[wrapper0, wrapper5]` are scanned. If the element is defined, the `background-color` style is set to `green`. If the element is not defined, assigning any style value is avoided as its value will be `null`.

```js
/**
 * In the solution below, if the selected element is not null, the background-color 
 * style is set to green.
 */
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
  let selectedElement = document.getElementById(`wrapper${i}`);

  if(selectedElement !== null) {
    selectedElement.style.setProperty('background-color', 'green');
    console.log(selectedElement);
  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper1, #wrapper2, #wrapper3, #wrapper4, #wrapper5 {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper0"></div>
<div id="wrapper1"></div>
<div id="wrapper2"></div>
<div id="wrapper3"></div>
<div id="wrapper4"></div>
<div id="wrapper5"></div>
```